# Inline Search Expand Results?

Tags: 2013, search, search-results, grouping

Can the 2013 inline search be made to expand results in a collapsed group-by View?

Not all users are smart enough - it seems - to realise that if you see grouped results after a search, you just have to click on the grouped items to expand the results:

[image]